# Merge two chromsome box data type which have one common edge

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics, genome

This is my data:

```
    > pos

  chrA        x     x_end  chrB        y    y_end
 chr11        0   3000000 chr19        0 20000000
 chr11 60000000  63500000 chr19        0 20000000
 chr11 63500000  67500000 chr19        0 20000000
 chr11 67500000  76000000 chr19        0 20000000
 chr11  3000000  20000000 chr19 27000000 29500000
 chr11 20000000  44000000 chr19 27000000 29500000
 chr11 44000000  49500000 chr19 27000000 29500000
 chr11 49500000  51500000 chr19 27000000 29500000
 chr11 54500000  60000000 chr19 27000000 29500000
 chr11 76000000 134500000 chr19 27000000 29500000
 chr11 60000000  63500000 chr19 32500000 34500000
 chr11        0   3000000 chr19 34500000 47500000
 chr11 60000000  63500000 chr19 34500000 47500000
 chr11 63500000  67500000 chr19 34500000 47500000
 chr11 67500000  76000000 chr19 34500000 47500000
 chr11        0   3000000 chr19 47500000 51500000
 chr11 60000000  63500000 chr19 47500000 51500000
 chr11 63500000  67500000 chr19 47500000 51500000
 chr11 67500000  76000000 chr19 47500000 51500000
 chr11 63500000  67500000 chr19 54000000 57000000
```

Every row is just like a rectangle box in a x~y matrix.

The `(x, y), (x, y_end), (x_end, y), (x_end, y_end)` are the coordinates of 4 vertex of a box.

I want to get these rows:

```
    for two rows(boxes) i and j,
    if their (x=x, x_end=x_end, y_end=y) or (y=y, y_end=y_end, x_end=x)
    get the two boxes and then merge into one box
```

my expected result is:

```
> res
 chrA        x     x_end  chrB        y    y_end
chr11        0   3000000 chr19        0 20000000
chr11 60000000  76000000 chr19        0 20000000
chr11  3000000  51500000 chr19 27000000 29500000
chr11 54500000  60000000 chr19 27000000 29500000
chr11 76000000 134500000 chr19 27000000 29500000
chr11        0   3000000 chr19 34500000 51500000
chr11 60000000  63500000 chr19 32500000 34500000
chr11 60000000  76000000 chr19 34500000 51500000
chr11 63500000  67500000 chr19 54000000 57000000
```

this is a figure to explain the question (Every box represent one row in pos). I want to merge the adjacent boxes into one larger rectangle box):
[image]

So the question can be simplified: how to merge these adjacent boxes?

And this is my code (it's inefficient and missed some box which should be merged.):

```
#find common edges and merge
  for (i in 1:(nrow(pos)-1) ){
    for (j in (i+1):nrow(pos)){
      if (pos[i, "x"] == pos[j, "x"] & pos[i, "x_end"] == pos[j, "x_end"] & pos[i, "y_end"] == pos[j, "y"] ){
        pos[j, "y"] <- pos[i, "y"]
        pos[i, "y_end"] <- pos[j, "y_end"]} 
      else if (pos[i, "x_end"] == pos[j, "x"] & pos[i, "y"] == pos[j, "y"] & pos[i, "y_end"] == pos[j, "y_end"]){
        pos[j, "x"] <- pos[i, "x"]
        pos[i, "x_end"] <- pos[j, "x_end"]}
    }
  }

pos <- unique(pos)
```

I hope there is a better way.

Comment: You probably don't have to iterate over all `j` rows if you sort first. (You could also cheat and use filled rectangles without outlines.)

Comment: Also note that the group of boxes in the top middle will be merged differently if you check horizontal or vertical first..

Comment: I don't get it... can you explain how you get the first row of your expected output. `chr11 60000000  76000000 chr19        0 20000000`. There the `x_end=x` doesn't fit, right?

Comment: @Jimbou, the first row of result is merged by input's 2,3,4 rows because they are adjacent.  `input's 2nd row's x = output's 1st row's x (60000000)`, `input's 4th row's x_end = output's 1st row's x_end (76000000)`, their y and y_end are same so no change.

Comment: @J.Wan But why do you don't want `chr11 54500000  60000000 chr19 27000000 29500000` or `chr11        0   3000000 chr19        0 20000000` as a result?

Comment: Why are we doing this?

Comment: @Jimbou Sorry, I missed some results. I have corrected it.

Comment: @Axeman I want to get the merged box's position. So filled rectangles maybe not a good way.

Comment: @zx8754 Actually, the question can be simplified: how to merge adjacent boxes? The chrosome position can be replaced by any other coordinate position. This issue maybe exist in many situations.

Comment: I agree it is an interesting problem. But why  are you doing this in bioinformatics context?